# Magento 2 Unexpected number in JSON at position 1

Tags: magento2, json

Am working on magento 2.3 and have an error in console product page,i have no idea what is it,i guess its fetching json data with error in product gallery part.

I tried every thing like clearing cache and re compiling the di.

here is the error

> VM106473:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at
>   position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at getNodeData (scripts.js:87)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at scripts.js:117
>       at HTMLDocument.apply (main.js:70)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.add [as done] (jquery.js:3291)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery.js:3542)
>       at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2967)
>       at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-migrate.js:241)

thanks for help

Comment: "I tried every thing like clearing cache and re compiling the di." wow..... just wow....

Comment: https://twitter.com/sandermangel/status/770637923658129408

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late, I found the issue, it was Magento-init script validation in my override addtocart module causing the problem, in nutshell its syntax error.